# Add handlers to all loggers in logging.config.dictConfig

Tags: python, logging

We are using the dictConfig function to configure our loggers.
I currently have a couple of handlers assigned to the root logger.

The problem is that I don't know all my loggers names in my config and I would like to assign the handlers to all loggers (that will be created after loading the config).

Currently my config looks like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': f'%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'Logzio':{
            'class': 'logzio.handler.LogzioHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'token': '<TOKEN>'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'root': {
            'handlers':['console', 'Logzio'],
            'formatter': 'default',
            'propagate': False,
            'level':'INFO',
        }
    }
}
```

Then I configure it in the beginning of my code:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

How can I assign the handlers to all my loggers (and not just the root)

Comment: You don't need to. It is sufficient to only configure the root logger. As all the descendent loggers forward messages through their parents to the root logger.

Comment: @DanD. you are right.  my problem was that the root logger is not called root, simply empty string. Thank you

Comment: @NotSoShabby It sounds like your solution was to change `'root'` to `''`. If so, please add it as a comment for others to find.

Comment: @DougHarris would love to, but it's been so long I don't remeber what I did. If you have the correct answer, feel free to add it and I will mark it as the right one for others to know. Cheers.

Comment: I'll give it a try and post an answer.

In the meantime, I notice a token for logzio in your code sample. If that's a real token, you should rotate it on the logzio side