# Combination of logging.config.dictConfig(logger_config) and logging.getLogger(__name__) not working

Tags: python, logging

To have all logs below level ERROR written to STDOUT I have tried to use a logger configuration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53257669/3737186):

```
class _ExcludeErrorsFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        """Only lets through log messages with log level below ERROR ."""
        return record.levelno < logging.ERROR

logger_config = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'exclude_errors': {
            '()': _ExcludeErrorsFilter
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        # Modify log message format here or replace with your custom formatter class
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ level=%(levelname)s message=\"%(message)s\" module=%(module)s name=%(name)s processName=%(processName)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_stderr': {
            # Sends log messages with log level ERROR or higher to stderr
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'stream': sys.stderr
        },
        'console_stdout': {
            # Sends log messages with log level lower than ERROR to stdout
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'formatter': 'default',
            'filters': ['exclude_errors'],
            'stream': sys.stdout
        }
    },
    'root': {
        # In general, this should be kept at 'NOTSET'.
        # Otherwise it would interfere with the log levels set for each handler.
        'level': 'NOTSET',
        'handlers': ['console_stderr', 'console_stdout']
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(logger_config)
```

But now no logs get written when I try to create a logger AFTER this configuration with

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I stress AFTER because I am aware of the `disable_existing_loggers` argument, so this can be ruled out as a cause.

What works is:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("root")
```

Now my question is:

How can I configure my loggers such that I can create separate loggers per python file with the configuration I desire to set (so it's not applying just to *root*.

Comment: I think there is some relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614823/add-handlers-to-all-loggers-in-logging-config-dictconfig) question

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I added above your code:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import sys

LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
```

and after your code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Foo')
```

and when I run it, it prints:

```
2023-11-10 17:57:27.836Z level=INFO message="Foo" module=so_77461324 name=__main__ processName=MainProcess
```